# Can open62541 pubsub objects, not only variables

Tags: opc-ua, open62541

The official open62541 example pubsub all use variables, and there is a macro UA_PUBSUB_DATASETFIELD_VARIABLE.

If I have an object, and there are only variables in the object, can I pubsub the entire object?

If not, is it a better way to change the object to a customized variable?

Answer (score 0):

1. I think no
2. Maybe yes,you can try use ExtensionObject for that. You can first create a custom structure, or just use a "plain structure" to contain all the variables